# Explanation required for the below python code

Tags: python-3.x

What will be output for the below code

```
for i in range(5):
  continue
print(i)
```

Since the variable is out of scope, why does the above code works. Also why does the value of i restricts to 4?

Comment: Because the variable *isn't* out of scope. And because `range` (like most things in Python) has an *exclusive* upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

It's iterating through the range, which is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] and doing nothing. "i" is the iterator, and the last one is "4", so you're printing it.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is not out of scope. Local variables in python are available everywhere in the function it is defined in. If it's not in a function, then the variable has global scope. This was probably done because, there is no need to declare variable in python, like we do in C or Java. Note that any variable you use inside the function is also available outside the loop.

For example:

```py
for foo in range(10):
    bar = 2
print(foo, bar)
```

This will print `9 2`.

As for your second question, most things in python have inclusive lower bounds and exclusive upper bounds. That means, `range(5)` is actually `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.
You can verify this by running `print(list(range(5)))`.
If you want the range `1-5`, you can use `range(1, 6)`.